# Regarding dynamic Value Replacement in Spring config

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I want to concatenate a string dynamically in springs.The string is

`<bean id="mBeanExporter" class="org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter" lazy-init="false">
        <property name="beans">
            <map>
                <entry key="bean:name=HealthChk" value-ref="#{'HealthChk-'.concat(_LOCALHOST_)}"/>
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="server" ref="mBeanServer"/>
    </bean>`

I am passing `_LOCALHOST_` value  from script which should replace this with the IPAddress.Can anyone help me out how the concat can be done?**value-ref="#{'HealthChk-'.concat(`_LOCALHOST_`)}** needs to be corrected.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The expression in the "#{}" placeholders is in the Spring Expression Language. String concatenation is just like Java (i.e. you use a "+" operator). See [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html) for details and examples.

Comment: Thanks for the info.For the String #{'HealthChk-'+$(_LOCALHOST_)}..Its failing.Can you Please tell me how the operator needs to be defined._LOCALHOST_ is dynamically replaced with the value configured in Script file.

Comment: What's the "Script file"? Maybe "#{'HealthChk-'+@environment.getProperty('LOCALHOST')}" (it depends what "LOCALHOST" is, how you should resolve it).